# How to crack KeePass database when knowing the first part of the master password

Tags: password-cracking, brute-force, keepass, dictionary, wordlist

I have a KeePass 2.47 database which is protected with a **master password** and a **key file**.

I managed to lose the 2nd part of my master password. So, I have access to the database, the key file and the first part of the master password (`ftyhbvGG`).

I can also provide some *educated guesses* on the parts of the 2nd (unknown) part of the password:

- character combination,
- likely character succession,
- overall password length

Does the fact that I know the first part of the master password and can provide educated guesses improve my cracking chances? If so, how I can make best of use of this?

Based on the above:

1. What would be my best cracking strategy? Some form of brute force?
2. How would I go about creating a wordlist (dictionary)?
3. Are there any automated cracking tools (Windows or Linux) appropriate for my situation? (For example, after some online searching, I found **mod0keecrack** https://github.com/devio/mod0keecrack but I don't know what `wordlist.txt` to use as input -- I assume other tools would also require similar input.)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+would+I+go+about+creating+a+wordlist+(dictionary)%3F

Comment: Knowing something about the password reduces the number of guesses you would have to make. Brute force is your *only* cracking strategy in this scenario. mod0keecrack  looks fine and its documentation tells you how to use a wordlist or stdin.

Comment: @schroeder I understand the usage of the wordlist but not how to populate it based on my current knowledge of the first part of the passrod + the "educated guesses". Do I just put `ftyhbvGG` in the wordlist? How can I make the wordlist use the `ftyhbvGG` to generate all other possible combinations? How can I input the "educated guesses" into the wordlist?

Comment: please see the linked answers or all the results from google I linked.

Comment: You tried just putting ftyhbvGG in the wordlist and it didn't work. The wordlist needs to be the "list of words" you want to try. So think in terms of *millions* of entries in the wordlist in your scenario ...